# direct GET works. image load does not

Tags: http, web, permissions

Ok, this is funny. I just installed a wordpress, and the images are not appearing. Firebug tells me I get a 403 forbidden error for all the images. However, if I copy and paste the url into the address bar, I get the image without any problem.

I don't get it (which is ok, considering it's almost 3 in the night)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem was hotlinking protection, which does not make sense anyway, since I am querying from within the same host. I disabled it and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

It must be looking at the Referer header.